# How to get values inserted into temp table to my original table in sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to create a temp table in my stored procedure in which one column I am getting using `scope_identity()` and the other column is itself an identity. What I want is that the temp table should get rows (which are multiple) corresponding to the single value of scope identity.

Like

```
columnA  ColumnB
------------------
111         X
111         Y
111         z
```

and then I want these values to be inserted into my original table. Is it possible How? Thank you

Comment: Your requirement is not very clear, I'm afraid.

Comment: the values that i am inserting into temp want all the values in my main table. That's it.

Comment: `scope_identity()` will give you the last identity created. How do you want "itself an identity" next to it? Won't it have 2 columns with the same value?